# Swift Filter a Json file within a bundle based on a query string

Tags: json, swift, swiftui

I am loading a json file from the application bundle as such:

```
if let fileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Picker.bundle/Data/MyCodes", withExtension: "json") {

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: fileURL) { (data, response, error) in

        do {

            if let d = data {

                let decodedLists = try JSONDecoder().decode([Codes].self, from: d)


                DispatchQueue.main.async {

                    self.code = decodedLists

                }

            } else {

                print("No Data")

            }

        } catch {

            print ("Error")

        }

    }.resume()

}
```

Is there anyway I can apply a filter so that it only read the code that have names that start with a certain string

Example.

the the query string would be "Can" it would traverse the json tree and only return children with Can i their name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After parsing JSON, you can [filter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/3018365-filter) result,

```
struct Codes {
    var title: String
}

DispatchQueue.main.async {
   //filter codes if title starts with "Can"
   self.code = decodedLists.filter { $0.title.hasPrefix("Can") }
   //filter codes if title contains the substring "Can"
   self.code = decodedLists.filter { $0.title.contains("Can") }
}
```